# Is it possible to have a POJO as ESuperType in EMF?

Tags: java, eclipse, emf, ecore

**Question/Problem**

Given a plain Java class coming from a non-EMF-aware API such as

```
public class BankAccount {
    String ownerName;
    int accountNumber;

    // ...
}
```

and also let's assume that I am not allowed to change or recompile this class (because it is from an API).

Is there any simple way to use this class as an ESuperType for an EClass in EMF? (And, of course, the single class is just an example. I'd need to wrap an API consisting of 30-50 classes ...).

**Own thoughts**

Personally, I think it is not possible out of the box.

I could only think of two ways, both with quite some effort and not easy to realize.

1. Create an Ecore model which reflects the original class (`EBankAccount`, having `ownerName` and `accountNumber` as `EAttributes`) and a utility method/mechanism that wraps the original object by copying its fields into the corresponding `EStructuralFeatures` and adds `EAdapter`s which are responsible to synchonize both objects.
2. Hook into EMF.CodeGen and do some magic there which makes it possible to have the original class as super class in the generated code which at the same time still fulfilling the EMF contract (= implement the `EObject` interface etc.).

But maybe there's some hidden feature of EMF (or an existing extension) which does something along these lines, and I am not aware of it?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me what you real want, but I will try to describe the several options.

If you want just to extend the POJO (which is what the question text suggests), the answer is YES, you can simply add a new EClass to your model and refer to the POJO qualified name in the "Instance Type Name" attribute. Then you can create other classes that extend from this one, but its state won't be managed by EMF.

But if you want EMF to track that POJO state as if it was a real EMF object (so those properties are also EStructuralFeature), then I don't see another solution, you really need to model it completely in EMF.

In this second case, both options you described seem possible.

1. The first option you described (and I assume you mean you want to synchronize the 2 objects, and not the 2 classes) seems the easiest one, and I don't think it would take so much effort if you use some generic method via reflection.
   This might be a good solution if you get the objects in very concrete locations, so you only need to wrap and unwrap in specific places. Otherwise you will need to convert be converting (wraping/unwrapping) the object all the time.
2. It may be also possible but it requires more effort for sure, since it's not easy to extend the Java JET templates

I'm not aware of any extension for this.

Comment: +1 for the "Instance Type Name" attribute. I have never used it. I'll play around with it and see what it does...